# How to make sure pch.h is the first included header using clang-format?

Tags: c++, clang-format, precompiled-headers

Some compilers require the pre-compiled-header to be included first. Clang-format can sort the headers (which is good). I want to make sure that pch will always be first.

How can I do this?

(My work around is to use `IncludeBlocksStyle: Preserve` and seperate `#include "pch.h"` from the rest.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative priorities in `IncludeCategories`, so you can do something like this:

```
IncludeBlocksStyle: Regroup
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex: '"pch.h"'
    Priority: -1000
  # Other groups definitions here
```

Comment: The regex is wrong. It can affect `#include "pchdh"`.